# php exif orientation - how to overwrite the upload image?

Tags: php, php-gd

I got a function to check php exif image orientation:

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name']));
$exif = exif_read_data($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name']);
if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
    switch($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 8:
            $image = imagerotate($image,90,0);
            break;
        case 3:
            $image = imagerotate($image,180,0);
            break;
        case 6:
            $image = imagerotate($image,-90,0);
            break;
    }
    $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'] = $image; // what to do here?
}
```

What I'd like to do is get the file user upload and overwrite it with the correct orientation before some more uploads tests. 
I tried

```
$_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'] = $image;
```

but it is not uploading the image after it. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`$_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name']` is a string variable containing the path to the file.

`$image` is a `gd resource`.

You need to instruct PHP to write the resource as a specific image format to the file location. For example, [as a JPEG](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php):

```
imagejpeg($image, $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name']);
```